# ScrollView Overlapping

Tags: android, android-layout, button, scrollview, splash-screen

I am building a simple splashscreen. The splashscreen has two buttons: sign in and sign up. Once the user clicks on sign in, I load a layout with two edittext fields for credentials to be entered, a button to proceed with logging in, and a cancel button to return back to the splash screen. The login layout is written in a scrollview. However, when I click on the Cancel button the scrollview still seems to be present. I have tried to set scrollview's visibility as gone but that crashes my application. I have tried to set visibility Invisible and that also crashes my application. I have done a lot of googling and there seems to be no solution.

```
package com.praveen.loginregi.app;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    Button signin;
    Button signup;
    Button cancel;
    Button signincancel;

    RelativeLayout login,register;
    LinearLayout fromsignin,selectsingn,fromactvitysignup;
    ScrollView sc;
    ScrollView sc1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        signin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSingIn);
        signup=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);
        login=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl);
        register=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl1);
        cancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btncancel);
        signincancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSingIncancel);
        sc=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.sc);
        sc1=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.sc1);

        fromsignin=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.from_actvity_sign_in);
        selectsingn=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.selectsingn);
        fromactvitysignup =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.from_actvity_sign_up);
        signin.setOnClickListener(this);
        signup.setOnClickListener(this);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
        signincancel.setOnClickListener(this);

        selectsingn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnSignUp:

                System.out.println("hhhijoihhohouhouhhhjhjhkkhgjgggjghjhgjhhhg");


                selectsingn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                selectsingn.setVisibility(View.GONE);




                register.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                fromactvitysignup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Animation ani2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_down);
                fromactvitysignup.startAnimation(ani2);




                return;


        case R.id.btnSingIn:
                System.out.println("djksfhjksdhdjkfhskjdhdskfjhfdkjhfksdjdfshkj");


                selectsingn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                login.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                selectsingn.setVisibility(View.GONE);



                fromsignin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Animation ani = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_down);
                fromsignin.startAnimation(ani);
                return;

            case R.id.btncancel:




                register.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                register.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                fromactvitysignup.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                selectsingn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                sc1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);




                return;

            case R.id.btnSingIncancel:


                login.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                login.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                selectsingn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                fromsignin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



                return;

            default:
                selectsingn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                fromsignin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                register.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                fromactvitysignup.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }

    }
}
```

XML Main Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MainActivity"
                android:background="@drawable/fire_logo">



    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/from_actvity_sign_in"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone">

        <include
                android:id="@+id/myid2"
                layout="@layout/activity_sign_in" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/from_actvity_sign_up"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone">

        <include
                android:id="@+id/myid3"
                layout="@layout/activity_sign_up_screen" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/linearlayout_bg"
            android:id="@+id/selectsingn"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            >

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:text="Sign Up"
                android:background="@drawable/button_default_bg"
                style="@style/DefaultButtonText"
                />
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSingIn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:text="Sign In"
                style="@style/DefaultButtonText"
                android:background="@drawable/button_default_bg"
                />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>




 Signin Layout/Signup Layout
```

<

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#80000000" android:fillViewport="false" android:id="@+id/sc">


    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:id="@+id/rl"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff">

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                >

            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etUserName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittext_top_bg"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:hint="Email"
                    android:textColorHint="#cccccc"/>
            />/  android:drawableLeft="@drawable/email"/>
            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etPass"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittext_bottom_bg"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:textColorHint="#cccccc"
                    android:password="true"/>
            />/  android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnSingIns1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:text="Sign In"
                    style="@style/DefaultButtonText"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_default_bg"
                    />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnSingIncancel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:text="Cancel"
                    style="@style/DefaultButtonText"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_default_bg"
                    />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I have the same xml code for sign up but with corresponding variables

```
       My logcat



        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.praveen.loginregi.app.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:203)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Signup Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#80000000"
            android:id="@+id/sc1"
        >
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:id="@+id/rl1"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:padding="10dp"
                >

            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etEmail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittext_top_bg"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:hint="Email"
                    android:textColorHint="#bbbbbb"
                    />
            />/ android:drawableLeft="@drawable/email"/>
            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etUserName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittext_default_bg"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:hint="User Name"
                    android:textColorHint="#bbbbbb"
                    />
            />/  android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user"/>
            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etPass"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittext_bottom_bg"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:textColorHint="#bbbbbb"
                    android:password="true"/>
            //android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnSignUpp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:text="Sign Up"
                    style="@style/DefaultButtonText"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_default_bg"
                    />


            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btncancel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:text="cancel"
                    style="@style/DefaultButtonText"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_default_bg"
                    />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: please add your xml codes here

Comment: Post your xml file..!!

Comment: please try post xml as well as logcat.

Comment: Your files won't compile, things are missing: R.id.btncancel R.id.rl1 R.id.sc1

Comment: Sc1 is in my other xml File Sign up, this is my sign in xml file.... I did not post it since it is the same code

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

Your problem is that you are changing the visibility of `@+id/rl1` which is the RelativeLayout nested in the `ScrollView` in `activity_sign_in.xml`, so when you click cancel and make the `RelativeLayout` invisible the `Scrollview` with the translucent background is still visible.

I think the easiest solution is to use the id you define in the include tag (variable `fromsignin`) in order to switch the visibility on/off.

**Longer answer:**

Looking at your Layout I don't get why didn't you just use a `Dialog` to display the sign_in, because you actually use a `ScrollView` to darken the background, and then nest a `LinearLayout` inside a `RelativeLayout`. Honestly I can't see why you need all that structure, you could easily accomplish the same effect by displaying the sign_in as a `Dialog` content and removing the `ScrollView` and the `RelativeLayout` from the layout.
Since I don't have the animation files I just didn't use it so maybe that's why you are using this structure, still the `RelativeLayout` seems useless to me as you can center with gravity tags.

EDIT:
I just tested this and it works fine with your source and layout.
Change the `fromsignin` visibility in the switch case for `R.id.btnSingIncancel` from VISIBLE to GONE

```
case R.id.btnSingIncancel:
                login.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  //this can be deleted
                login.setVisibility(View.GONE);       //this too, and redundant as well.
                selectsingn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                fromsignin.setVisibility(View.GONE);    //This line is the important one!
                return;
```

Comment: Thank you momo for replying butnope hiding fromsign did not work and I looked up Dialog in google,the code seems to be even more tedious                 http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html....please suggest me a solution with this context

Comment: I added example, check it ;-)

Comment: no :( i already tried that and tried it again....if u click cancel the background gets filled with the scrollview, Splash screen -> sigin-> cancel
Splash screen -> signup-> cancel
Splash screen -> sigin-> cant acess any button
when I switch to sign in I am not able to click any of the buttons,the scroll view blocks it